# Should I ask to join team meetings?

Tags: professionalism, communication, meetings

I work in a smaller company with few technical staff. I am a newer part of the technical team, I do mainly operational stuff; the other team members are engineers/architects.

They often have many impromptu meetings with the CTO to discuss projects and new issues. I am rarely invited to these meetings, even when I know the content is relevant to my job. I don't want to waste anyone's time by joining these meetings, but I feel isolated and don't like wasting time asking something that was resolved during the meeting.

My question is if I should bother asking to join these meetings & if it's my place to ask.

Comment: "I don't want to waste anyone's time by joining these meetings, but I feel isolated and don't like wasting time" - the only time wasted would be your own - they're all already having the meeting

Answer (score 3):

> Should I ask to join team meetings?

"They often have many **impromptu** meetings with the CTO to discuss projects and new issues."

The key to your question is the word "impromptu".  The only way I know of to handle this is to just join these meetings when its necessary.  This is even **more important** when it is related to your job.

It doesn't sound like this is happening on purpose, so I am not sure what else you can do but just be present where appropriate.  Eventually the CTO will most likely start inviting you to these un-scheduled meetings as they realize what areas your responsible for.

Comment: I had that exact problem, and when someone mentioned the meetings afterwards I started to say "I'm sorry, I didn't know there was a meeting on this subject. Did you need me there?" . They eventually realized that I could indeed be helpful, and started asking me to join when I was involved in the projects. You have to trust your colleague's judgement on that :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Should (you) bother asking to join these meetings & (is) it (your) place to
>   ask?

If in the process of your day to day tasks you come to realise that it might be more efficient, or beneficial to be included in these meetings then it is obviously relevant to the work assigned to you by your superiors.

There is no harm in pointing out the benefits of being in those meetings to your manager/supervisor, and it is absolutely within the purview of your job to ensure you are working as efficiently as possible.

I don't think any manager/supervisor would have a problem with you suggesting or asking for something reasonable that will have a positive impact on the quality and or efficiency of your day to day work output.

---

I would recommend starting a short conversation with your manager/supervisor/CTO along the lines of:

> Morning/Afternoon 'X' do you mind If I borrow some of your time to
>   talk about the meetings that the engineers/architects jump into from
>   time to time.

***await response as to if he/she has time to spare at the moment***

If they do:

> Would it be ok if I jump into the room with them, as some of the
>   discussions/outcomes would be really useful in speeding up the work
>   that i'm doing.

If they dont, simply set up a time when you can discuss it.

---

**I wouldn't** necessarily just invite yourself into the meetings, because there could be instances when it genuinely isn't useful to you or your work. I'd start with approching a senior to make sure you get an invite into the first 'impromtu' meeting that occurs after your discussion. Then after that the engineers/architects will  likely see the value of your presence.